# Add Custom Discount woccommerce add order from admin

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

**I need to add a custom discount option in woocommerce when add order from admin.**

I used `woocommerce_before_calculate_totals` hook for front side a working fine for front order. Is any hook available for admin side?

Thanks,
Bharat Bhola

Answer (score 1):

You can add your custom discount by using     wc_admin_custom_order_field_options 
It should work.